# Populating a list using android listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to populate the result onto a listview once I press the search button. But, when i try to do it, nothing is displayed on the listview.

I am using asynctask to get the data from database and pass it into the listview as a array.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Below are the code:

```
public class FindFriends extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText handphone;
Button searchbtn;
String name,hp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findfriends);
    handphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterfn);

    searchbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchfor);
    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    String[] values = new String[]{name};

    ArrayAdapter<String> codeLearnArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    listview.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.searchfor:
            hp = handphone.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin().execute(hp);
            break;
    }

}


class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "address_url";

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("hp", args[0]);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(FindFriends.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                name = json.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

findfriends.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/findfriends"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/enterfn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter handphone number/username to start searching"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/enterfn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/searchfor"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enterfn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchfor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Android.

Anyway I can't see where you update your array, in the AsyncTask you download the data but you don't update values. So you shuld update the array passed to the adapter and then call the it's method notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Just go through  the below code and replcae it with your,

```
public class FindFriends extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText handphone;
Button searchbtn;
String name = "name", hp = "hp";


ListView listview;
ArrayAdapter<String> codeLearnArrayAdapter;
ArrayList<String> values;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findfriends);
    handphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterfn);

    searchbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchfor);
    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // adding value to arrayList
    values.add(name);

    codeLearnArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    listview.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.searchfor:
            hp = handphone.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin(new MyHandler()).execute(hp);
            break;
    }

}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "address_url";
    MyHandler myHandler;

    public AttemptLogin(MyHandler myHandler) {
        this.myHandler = myHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("hp", args[0]);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(FindFriends.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                name = json.getString("name");
                Message message = new Message();
                message.obj = name;
                myHandler.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String response = String.valueOf(msg);
        values.add(response);
        codeLearnArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

And let me know if it works...

Comment: Nope. my whole app crashed when i tried to enter the page

Answer (score 0):

you missed `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Use this method after data changing

**UPD**

try this code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    if (json != null) {
        Toast.makeText(FindFriends.this, json.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            name = json.getString("name");
            values[0]=name;
            codeLearnArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works. Otherwise let me know about it.

P.S. You should also use List instead of array.

Comment: name = json.getString("name");
 codeLearnArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); Tried to put here but it doesn't work. Any advise?

Comment: Your listview shows data stored in `values` array. When data changed, you should save it into `values` and call `codeLearnArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ` to let adapter know about data change.